# Compiling servlet giving error message

Tags: java, servlets

### I ran the following command to compile a servlet called BeerSelect.java from HeadFirst Servlets and JSP book.

D:\Apache Tomcat\apache-tomcat-5.5.36\apache-tomcat-5.5.36\webapps\Coffee>javac
-classpath /common/lib servlet-api.jar:classes: -d classes src/com/example/web/B
eerSelect.java

My servlet-api.jar is located in `D:\Apache Tomcat\apache-tomcat-5.5.36\apache-tomcat-5.5.36\common\lib`

### MESSAGE

```
javac: invalid flag: servlet-api.jar:classes:
Usage: javac <options> <source files> use -help for a list of possible options
```

---

Cannot understand how to fix this command  and compile the servlet. Doing it for the first time new to servlets.

Then I changed the command to be

```
D:\Apache Tomcat\apache-tomcat-5.5.36\apache-tomcat-5.5.36\webapps\Coffee\WEB-IN
F\src\com\example\web>javac -classpath "D:\Apache Tomcat\apache-tomcat-5.5.36\ap
ache-tomcat-5.5.36\common\lib\servlet-api.jar";classes  BeerSelect.java
```

### MESSAGE

```
BeerSelect.java:3: package com.example.model does not exist
import com.example.model.*;
^
BeerSelect.java:15: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class BeerExpert
location: class com.example.web.BeerSelect
        BeerExpert be = new BeerExpert();
        ^
BeerSelect.java:15: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class BeerExpert
location: class com.example.web.BeerSelect
        BeerExpert be = new BeerExpert();
                            ^
BeerSelect.java:32: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable out
location: class com.example.web.BeerSelect
         out.println("<br>try: " + it.next());
         ^
4 errors
```

Why cannot it find the com.example.model package ?

### IMAGE[image]

Comment: Why don't you use a proper development environment? Ok, using and knowing `javac` is important, but I think at this level, you would spare yourself an enormous amount of frustration by using one.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have three issues with your command: extra spaces, Unix-style pathnames, and missing additional Java source files. Try the following instead:

```
javac -classpath "D:\Apache Tomcat\apache-tomcat-5.5.36\apache-tomcat-5.5.36\common\lib\servlet-api.jar";classes -d classes src\com\example\web\*.java src\com\example\model\*.java
```

I've removed extra spaces, converted Unix paths to Windows paths, changed the classpath separator from the Unix-style ':' to Windows-style ';', and added your other Java sources - compiling them all together should resolve your first three compiler errors.

As for the last compiler error, that appears to be a genuine source code error - try prepending `System.` to the `out.println("<br>try: " + it.next());` line. (It can also be resolved by a static import, but that would be unconventional.)

Comment: You command worked in removing the first error however , I came across another one. I have edited the question above for your reference.Thank you!

Comment: Answer revised; I think that may fix the remaining issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
D:\Apache Tomcat\apache-tomcat-5.5.36\apache-tomcat-5.5.36\webapps\Coffee>javac -classpath "D:\Apache Tomcat\apache-tomcat-5.5.36\apache-tomcat-5.5.36\common\lib\servlet-api.jar";"D:\Apache Tomcat\apache-tomcat-5.5.36\apache-tomcat-5.5.36\webapps\Coffee\WEB-INF\src" WEB-INF\src\com\example\web\BeerSelect.java
```

This command works and compiles the class BeerSelect.java.